# Two different projects (different index.php's) on same server

Tags: linux, apache, centos, mod-alias

I'm trying to run two different php frameworks on the same server. The framework to use is determined by the first path in the uri.

So for example:

> http://www.example.com/v1/requestname

will go to the index.php located in:

> /var/www/html/api/api

And everything else (http://www.example.com/v2/requestname) will go to the index.php located in:

> /var/www/html/api2/public

Here is my apache 2.2 config:

```
Alias /v1 /var/www/html/api/api
<Directory /var/www/html/api/api>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/api2/public"
<Directory "/var/www/html/api2/public">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
</Directory>
```

I've been attempting to do this with apache, but every request is being routed to api2. Everything I'm looking seems to say this should work.

Comment: You _did_ restart the http server process after changing the configuration, didn't you? And you _did_ make a "deep reload" in your browser or alternatively delete the browser cache after the changes? And you also _did_ use a slightly different configuration that actually defines "v2" unilke the one shown above?

Comment: restart httpd? yes. deep reload? yes.  

Not sure if I'm understanding your third question though.  

Edit: I just notice that "http://www.example.com/v1/" works, but "http://www.example.com/v1/request", does not.

Comment: Did you see anything in the apache error log?

Comment: no. I've been watching it and there aren't any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the solution I came up with for anyone in the future:

Set anything beginning with /v1 to be send to the first version of the API.

```
Alias /v1 /var/www/html/api/api/index.php
```

Send everything else to the second version:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/api2/public"
<Directory "/var/www/html/api2/public">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
</Directory>
```

The trick was adding index.php onto the end of the Alias.